# Editing the source of a display for posts (to category recent)

Tags: javascript, infinite-scroll

I am trying to modify a piece of code that right now just pulls posts that have been selected in admin. The goal is to get rid of that source (I don't want to select posts), and just display posts from a category by recency.

Also (but I can put this off as the next thing to attempt), I would like the option of using Infinite Scroll OR the Load More button (right now there is a Load More button).

I have been learning html/php/css but javascript is something I a now setting out into.

Thanks for reading!

Here is the code right now:

```
<?php
// list tabs blocks
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') > 1 ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$wp_query = new WP_Query();

$wp_query->query(array('post_type' => 'portfolio', 
                         'order' => 'DESC', 
                         'paged' => $paged,
                         'post_status'     => 'publish',
                         'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page')
                      ));

$totalpostcount = 0;

if ( have_posts() ) :

    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();

        $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'portfolio-types');
        $cats = '';
        $names = '';
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            $cats .= $term->slug.' ';
            $names .= $term->name.' / ';
        }

        $cats = substr($cats, 0, -1);
        $names = substr($names, 0, -3);
        ?>

        <div data-id="id-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" data-alpha="<?php echo $cats; ?>" class="box">
            <a id="port-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" href="#" class="link ctive-link" onclick="" style="width:227px; height:195px;">
                <span class="overlay">&nbsp;</span>
                <span class="text"><strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong> <?php echo $names; ?></span>

                <?php 
                if(has_post_thumbnail()): 
                    $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumb'); ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $image_url[0]; ?>" alt="" />
                <?php else: ?>
                    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/images/thumb.jpg" alt="" />
                <?php endif; ?>
            </a>
        </div>

        <?php 
        $totalpostcount++;

    endwhile;
    ?>

    <?php 
    if(function_exists('genarate_ajax_pagination')) 
    genarate_ajax_pagination('Load More', 'white', 'content-portfolio', array('post_type' => 'portfolio')); 
    ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: On which template/page is this

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. It's in the content-home.php ("Home Page Template")